# Tumblr Follow Api

Tags: api, tumblr

I am trying to to add a custom Tumblr follow button to my site and I've been trying to figure out how the follow api works.

I've been using https://apigee.com/console/tumblr to test various requests and so for I can make the get requests work, but not the post requests. Specifically, I would like to be able to follow a blog.

For instance, if i want to follow  mcupdate The post request should look like this

http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/follow?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmcupdate.tumblr.com

This returns 404 page not found. As do any and all variations that I can think of. Since the get requests work fine, I am assuming that the credentials that apigee.com generates are fine. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks.